# how to create class variable dynamically in python

Tags: python, class, class-variables

I need to make a bunch of class variables and I would like to do it by looping through a list like that:

```
vars=('tx','ty','tz') #plus plenty more

class Foo():
    for v in vars:
        setattr(no_idea_what_should_go_here,v,0)
```

is it possible? I don't want to make them for an instance (using self in the __init__) but as class variables.

Comment: Why not to hold them in dict?

Comment: Do you want to share theses variables between different instances?

Comment: not sure. most likely. the requirement comes from an API and I don't know how they are used in there.

Comment: could this possibly be called in `__new__`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can run the insertion code immediately after a class is created:

```
class Foo():
     ...

vars=('tx', 'ty', 'tz')  # plus plenty more
for v in vars:
    setattr(Foo, v, 0)
```

Also, you can dynamically store the variable while the class is being created:

```
class Bar:
    locals()['tx'] = 'texas'
```

Comment: ah. that's cool. I will give it a go and see if the API I work with can handle that. thanks mate!

Comment: What if you've overridden __setattr__()?

Comment: Update... I figured it out.   Within ```__setattr__()``` you can call ```super(ThisClass, self).__setattr__(varname, varvalue)```.

Comment: Regarding the last part of the answer,`locals()['tx'] = 'texas'`. It should be said that the Python documentation specifically warns against this: *Note: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.* Link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: The locals for a class dictionary are modifiable.  It is the locals for a function that will be ignored.

Answer (score 10):

Late to the party but use the [`type` class constructor](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#type)!

```
Foo = type("Foo", (), {k: 0 for k in ("tx", "ty", "tz")})
```

Answer (score 9):

If for any reason you can't use Raymond's answer of setting them up after the class creation then perhaps you could use a metaclass:

```
class MetaFoo(type):
    def __new__(mcs, classname, bases, dictionary):
        for name in dictionary.get('_extra_vars', ()):
            dictionary[name] = 0
        return type.__new__(mcs, classname, bases, dictionary)

class Foo(): # For python 3.x use 'class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo):'
    __metaclass__=MetaFoo # For Python 2.x only
    _extra_vars = 'tx ty tz'.split()
```

Comment: This will not work as your solution has hard coded the values for `_extra_vars`.

Comment: @MSS you don't have to use `'tx ty tz'.split()`, you are allow to substitute your own expression which could reference a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The `locals()` version did not work for me in a class.

The following can be used to dynamically create the attributes of the class:

```
class namePerson:
    def __init__(self, value):
        exec("self.{} = '{}'".format("name", value)

me = namePerson(value='my name')
me.name # returns 'my name'
```

Comment: This is an awfully wrong approach. You are setting an instance variable, not a class variable. Also why don't you simply use `setattr`?

Answer (score 1):

`setattr(object, name, value)`
This is the counterpart of `getattr()`. The arguments are an object, a string and an arbitrary value. The string may name an existing attribute or a new attribute. The function assigns the value to the attribute, provided the object allows it.
For example, `setattr(x, 'name', value)` is equivalent to `x.name = value`.

Answer (score 0):

The function you need is:

`setattr(obj, name, value)`

This allows you to set named attributes for a given class (this can be `self`).

The built in documentation for this function is pretty self-explanatory:

```
Signature: setattr(obj, name, value, /)
Docstring:
Sets the named attribute on the given object to the specified value.

setattr(x, 'y', v) is equivalent to ``x.y = v''
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

**Example use**

One use of this is to use a dictionary to set multiple class attributes, in my case this was from *xpath* definitions. I felt this improved maintainability by keeping potentially more fragile xpath definitions all in one place:

```
class Person:
    def _extract_fields(self):
        ''' Process the page using XPath definitions '''
        logging.debug("_extract_fields(): {}".format(repr(self)))
        # describe how to extract data from the publicly available site
        # (kept together for maintainability)
        fields = {
            'staff_name':
            '//div[@id="staff_name"]//text()',
            'staff_dob':
            '(//div[@id="staff_dob"]//text())[1]'
        }
        # populate named class attributes from the dict
        for key in fields:
            setattr(self, key, self._parsed_content.xpath(fields[key]))

    def __init__(self):
        self._extract_fields()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create global variables with "foo." (or the name of your class) at the beggining of the name:

```
vars=('tx','ty','tz') #plus plenty more

class Foo():
    pass

foo = Foo() # Instance the class

for i in vars:
    globals () ["foo." + i] = value
```